# Add a value to a button for jquery function

Tags: jquery

For my project i want to add a button which changes on click and save data with a post function. The button :

```
<button 
   class="btn btn-primary favorit-btn2" 
   type="button" >
```

I add the buttons in a for loop,while adding the buttons i can add an id value with $button->id

what i want is add the id from the loop to the button so when i click the button i can use the id value in the function.

my function looks like :

```
 $(function() 
{
    $(".favorit-btn2").click(function() 
    {        
        if ( $(this).hasClass("favorit-btn2") ) 
        {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-primary');
        }    

        // DO SOMETHING WITH THE ID 
    });
});
```

I thought about adding an onCLick="myFunction($idvalue)" to the button but that would make it not possible to use the $(this) selector.

I rather not add it like id="$idvalue" to every button because of css reasons, it feels weird to add an id atribute to a button only to save the value.
my question is where should i add the id value to the button so i can use it in my click function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

You can use `.data()` function of `jQuery` to get value of data attribute of an element.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b2f8cyuc/)**

```
<button 
   class="btn btn-primary favorit-btn2" 
   data-id="1" 
   type="button" >

$(function () {
    $(".favorit-btn2").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("favorit-btn2")) {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-primary');
        }

        // DO SOMETHING WITH THE ID 
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Comment: I rather not add it as an id for css reasons. i dont like the idea of every button having an unique id